# Refresh only a div ("content") by universal button working on every page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

To be clear - Ive already checked other Questions about refreshing `div` and the ideas I found were not exactly what I look for.

My site is made of plenty pages with the same header and footer (top, bottom, menu on both sides). I use smarty templates, and the `Whole action` of every page happens in one `<div id="content">`. 
My users use to refresh most of those pages many times to do an action they've already done once again. With refreshing browser loads again header, footer, viewed page etc. I would like to bring them the button (instead of F5) which will refresh just a current content page (e.g. account.php) without refreshing whole site.

One of plenty structure:

```
<?php
$title = 'OneOfPlenty';
require_once("includes/head.php");

{
Whole action
}

require_once("includes/foot.php");
?>
```

---

```
header.tpl ends with <div id="content"> then comes
onofplenty.tpl and then in
footer.tpl I got </div> (close the content)
```

Here comes the question: Is it even possible? Am I able to create such a flexible button which will recognize which page is being displayed and will "know" to refresh just the content of this page?

Any ideas and help will be aprreciated.

Thank you
TTed

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want to reload only a section of a page using a button, instead of reloading the whole page, right?

Comment: Yes exactly! ;] But what important it is not just one static page. This button should work on every of user browse (account.php, statistics.php, mail.php etc. etc.)

Comment: Why do you include `head.php` and `foot.php` if you use smarty templates?

Comment: Huh why not? I'm not so pro and maybe I dont know about something. Is it wrong? In head.php as well as in foot.php I got the "static" content which is the same for every page. There are tpl files for each one also (header.tpl, footer.tpl).

Comment: You would usually have a basic template (`.tpl` file), where you include the `head.tpl` and the `footer.tpl` (or `foot.tpl`). This is the concept of using a templating engine like smarty.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an Ajax call with jQuery to get the output html of the tpl file of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Ajax call, e.g. by using the [jQuery `get()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), e.g. like this

```
$.get("includes/account.php", function(data) {
    $("#content").html(data);
    alert("Load was performed.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you saved some kind of variable, either to session or to a data-content on your div. Just so you know which page you are on. Say if you are on account.php you set $('#content').attr("data-content", "account"). Then if you press the refresh button you could use an ajax get on $('#content').attr("data-content") + 'php' to re-import the data. Could be done with a SESSION variable as well.